# Movement system with functions for text RPG

Tags: c++, function

I am a beginner student of C++ and I am currently working on a text RPG. I've been able to implement various functions that help the user check location, interact with items, check inventory, look around, and so on, but I cannot seem to get a good working movement system.

Now, I understand that OOP is obviously going to be MUCH more efficient and less frustrating than going the function route, but I am doing this for a class, and we haven't learned anything about classes/objects yet (We haven't even gone over vectors/arrays in our class).

Here is my code to try and get the movement working:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>

using namespace std;

void movement(string action, int& currentRoom) {
    if (action == "MOVE NORTH") { 
        if (currentRoom == 1) {
            currentRoom = 2;
            // This part is just to check if the loop happened and changed values.
            cout  << currentRoom << " " << "You are now in room two." << endl;
            }
        }
    }

int main() {
    int currentRoom;
    string action;

    cout << "Type 'move [direction]'" << endl;
    currentRoom = 1;
    getline(cin, action);
    boost::to_upper(action);

    // This is to check (for testing purposes for me) to see if the string 
    // converted to uppercase properly.
    cout << action << endl;

    getline(cin, action);
    movement(action, currentRoom);
}
```

Now, this is not final code that I'm implementing into my game. I've just created a small file to try and work out the logic/syntax of this movement function. When I run this code, I am able to type in 'move north' and it successfully translates into MOVE NORTH, but the function doesn't seem to be calling or doing anything. What am I doing wrong here? Is there any way I can make this easier for myself, without fully leaning into OOP?

Like I said, I haven't been able to learn classes/objects aside from a bit of reading I've done online, and I feel like I would be taking on too much right now to try and learn/implement them properly in such a short time... but maybe it would be for the better if I did? I am not sure.

Any help and input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a perfect case to experiment with some [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). Explain the code, statement by statement, to your "rubber duck" (imaginary or not), and see if it helps.

Comment: Never heard of that concept before, but it was a very interesting process to go through. I am resetting my input by calling getline before the function call, voiding my original "MOVE NORTH". Thank you very much for that!

Comment: Very good when you don't have any (more or less willing) friends or family around, or a whole Internet of strangers available... ;)

Comment: *"I understand that OOP is obviously going to be MUCH more efficient and less frustrating than going the function route"* ... I would mildly disagree, OOP design for this particular task will probably lead to *considerably* more elegant source, but *considerably* is less than *much*. My point is, that a well designed procedural source for the same task may be surprisingly elegant too, not lacking that much. If you feel like really chained down by procedural approach and that your code is too convoluted/mess, maybe you aren't exploiting the procedural C-like syntax to the full extent.

Comment: Also keep in mind the first (and often second) version of any source is almost always a mess... :) Even if you are experienced programmer. Rewriting at least once or twice is often best approach, to not spend too much time over-thinking the first version, but to get reasonable source code for future.

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {
    int currentRoom;
    string action;

    cout << "Type 'move [direction]'\n";
    currentRoom = 1;
    getline(cin, action);
    boost::to_upper(action);

    cout << action << '\n'; // here you verify

    getline(cin, action);   // but then you read again from stdin 
    movement(action, currentRoom); // and pass it on without changing it toupper.
}
```

Comment: Jeez, yes, that was quite a simple error there on my part. Thank you for the reply!